# Use wpa_supplicant without plain text passwords

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant, security

I'm running gentoo on my laptop, and I'm currently using [wpa_supplicant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wpa_supplicant) to handle wifi.

My configuration works and I can connect, but it is required to type in the plain text password into the configuration file. This doesn't work if I want to connect to a friend's wifi and they want to type in the password instead of telling me what it is. There's no security with plain text passwords.

How can I make this more secure so that some sort of encrypted password is stored instead of plaintext?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`wpa_passphrase [ ssid ] [ passphrase ]` generates a WPA PSK from an ASCII passphrase for a SSID. Then store it as

```
network={
        ssid="your ssid"
        psk=outputfromabove
}
```

Comment: oh great, thanks. Do you know of any option to have it take the passphrase as a linux password where it doesn't show the characters?

Comment: Do `history -c` instead.

Comment: Or do `xargs -n 2 wpa_passphrase` followed by `ssid` and `passphrase` each on its own line, followed by `C-d`.

Comment: This adds no security.  While the password is not stored in plain text, knowing the PSK is enough to connect to the network.

Comment: I'm just answering the question. In any case, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography).

Comment: This works for the case of the SSID with a single pass phrase (psk=...).  Is there a way to do the same for the SSID / identity / password case (password=...)?

Comment: It adds security. My work uses the AD password for wifi. I don't want my AD password sitting around un-hashed.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can leave the password entry blank. If you're running `wpa_gui`, it will prompt you for the password. (I do this with eduroam accounts, as my password is the same as my *nix login)